# 503 status in case of starting spring configuration server via docker-compose

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose, http-status-code-503, configserver

I've created demo configuration server using spring boot. It works fine.

`$ curl GET http://localhost:9090/actuator/health
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: GET
{"status":"UP"}%`

I use as parent project

```
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
```

dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Next step is to wrap the service via docker. `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM java:8-jre
VOLUME /tmp
ADD target/*.jar app.jar
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode"
ENTRYPOINT java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar
EXPOSE 9090
```

Creating independent docker image and starting container it works like expected:

```
$ docker build .
>> ... <imageName>
$ docker run -p 9090:9090 <imageName>
```

Creating `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  config-server:
    build: config-server
    ports:
     - "9090:9090"
    expose:
     - "9090"
    networks:
     - "my-network"

networks:
  my-network:
```

Starting and checking result:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
$ curl GET http://localhost:9090/actuator/health
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: GET
{"status":"DOWN"}%
```

Log trace looks ok:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
2018-07-13 14:00:23.804  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6fadae5d: startup date [Fri Jul 13 14:00:23 UTC 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-07-13 14:00:24.409  INFO 7 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a6513cca] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.3.RELEASE)

2018-07-13 14:00:24.774  INFO 7 --- [           main] e.m.c.ConfigServerApplication            : The following profiles are active: docker
2018-07-13 14:00:24.792  INFO 7 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@5b87ed94: startup date [Fri Jul 13 14:00:24 UTC 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6fadae5d
2018-07-13 14:00:25.866  INFO 7 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=68ad2e34-6263-3fe6-b377-5579821a13f0
2018-07-13 14:00:25.954  INFO 7 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a6513cca] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-07-13 14:00:26.335  INFO 7 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9090 (http)
2018-07-13 14:00:26.393  INFO 7 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-07-13 14:00:26.393  INFO 7 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
2018-07-13 14:00:26.413  INFO 7 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib]
2018-07-13 14:00:26.560  INFO 7 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-07-13 14:00:26.561  INFO 7 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1768 ms
2018-07-13 14:00:28.187  INFO 7 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-07-13 14:00:28.194  INFO 7 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-13 14:00:28.195  INFO 7 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-13 14:00:28.195  INFO 7 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-13 14:00:28.196  INFO 7 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-13 14:00:28.196  INFO 7 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpTraceFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-13 14:00:28.196  INFO 7 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webMvcMetricsFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-13 14:00:28.482  INFO 7 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-07-13 14:00:28.771  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@5b87ed94: startup date [Fri Jul 13 14:00:24 UTC 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6fadae5d
2018-07-13 14:00:28.907  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-07-13 14:00:28.909  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-07-13 14:00:28.922  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/encrypt],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.cloud.config.server.encryption.EncryptionController.encrypt(java.lang.String,org.springframework.http.MediaType)
2018-07-13 14:00:28.923  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/encrypt/{name}/{profiles}],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.cloud.config.server.encryption.EncryptionController.encrypt(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.http.MediaType)
2018-07-13 14:00:28.923  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/decrypt/{name}/{profiles}],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.cloud.config.server.encryption.EncryptionController.decrypt(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.http.MediaType)
2018-07-13 14:00:28.923  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/decrypt],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.cloud.config.server.encryption.EncryptionController.decrypt(java.lang.String,org.springframework.http.MediaType)
2018-07-13 14:00:28.924  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/encrypt/status],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> org.springframework.cloud.config.server.encryption.EncryptionController.status()
2018-07-13 14:00:28.924  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/key],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.cloud.config.server.encryption.EncryptionController.getPublicKey()
2018-07-13 14:00:28.924  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/key/{name}/{profiles}],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.cloud.config.server.encryption.EncryptionController.getPublicKey(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2018-07-13 14:00:28.935  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/{name}-{profiles}.properties],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.properties(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean) throws java.io.IOException
2018-07-13 14:00:28.936  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/{label}/{name}-{profiles}.json],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.labelledJsonProperties(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean) throws java.lang.Exception
2018-07-13 14:00:28.936  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/{name}/{profiles:.*[^-].*}],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.cloud.config.environment.Environment org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.defaultLabel(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2018-07-13 14:00:28.937  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/{name}-{profiles}.yml || /{name}-{profiles}.yaml],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.yaml(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean) throws java.lang.Exception
2018-07-13 14:00:28.937  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/{name}/{profiles}/{label:.*}],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.cloud.config.environment.Environment org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.labelled(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2018-07-13 14:00:28.937  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/{name}-{profiles}.json],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.jsonProperties(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean) throws java.lang.Exception
2018-07-13 14:00:28.938  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/{label}/{name}-{profiles}.properties],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.labelledProperties(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean) throws java.io.IOException
2018-07-13 14:00:28.938  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/{label}/{name}-{profiles}.yml || /{label}/{name}-{profiles}.yaml],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.labelledYaml(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean) throws java.lang.Exception
2018-07-13 14:00:28.944  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/{name}/{profile}/**],methods=[GET],params=[useDefaultLabel]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.cloud.config.server.resource.ResourceController.retrieve(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,boolean) throws java.io.IOException
2018-07-13 14:00:28.944  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/{name}/{profile}/{label}/**],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.cloud.config.server.resource.ResourceController.retrieve(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,boolean) throws java.io.IOException
2018-07-13 14:00:28.944  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/{name}/{profile}/{label}/**],methods=[GET],produces=[application/octet-stream]}" onto public synchronized byte[] org.springframework.cloud.config.server.resource.ResourceController.binary(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException
2018-07-13 14:00:28.986  INFO 7 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-07-13 14:00:28.987  INFO 7 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-07-13 14:00:29.666  INFO 7 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2018-07-13 14:00:29.683  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/health],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-07-13 14:00:29.684  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/info],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-07-13 14:00:29.686  INFO 7 --- [           main] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto protected java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.Link>> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.links(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-07-13 14:00:29.755  INFO 7 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-07-13 14:00:29.766  INFO 7 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'environmentManager' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-07-13 14:00:29.768  INFO 7 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'configurationPropertiesRebinder' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-07-13 14:00:29.769  INFO 7 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'refreshScope' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-07-13 14:00:29.772  INFO 7 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'environmentManager': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager]
2018-07-13 14:00:29.789  INFO 7 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'refreshScope': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh:name=refreshScope,type=RefreshScope]
2018-07-13 14:00:29.819  INFO 7 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinder': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties:name=configurationPropertiesRebinder,context=5b87ed94,type=ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder]
2018-07-13 14:00:29.925  INFO 7 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9090 (http) with context path ''
2018-07-13 14:00:29.931  INFO 7 --- [           main] e.m.c.ConfigServerApplication            : Started ConfigServerApplication in 7.179 seconds (JVM running for 7.857)
2018-07-13 14:00:34.931  INFO 7 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-07-13 14:00:34.932  INFO 7 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-07-13 14:00:34.965  INFO 7 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 33 ms
```

Is any idea how to fix health status of the service that is started in `docker-compose`?

Comment: I think it should be `curl -X GET http://localhost:9090/actuator/health`, please refer to `man curl`

Comment: @AlexKarshin, `curl` is not problem here, because it provides correct server response. But server response reports about issue and last one is trouble.

Comment: It is possible to configure the health endpoint to show details using the following application property `management.endpoint.health.show-details=always`. Maybe it will be helpful to understand why the app is DOWN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time I started containers, they were created successfully. They were dropped also successfully directly, before starting new ones. Last time I used instruction:

```
docker-compose down
```

to drop containers managed by `docker-compose` in automatic way.

That seems clear.

...But! The issue was in already created images. And images was not updated. To confirm my assumption I dropped correspond image and every thing was fixed. To make it in automatic way I've detected `docker-compose` additional useful flags and I use now:

```
docker-compose down --rmi local
```

- `--rmi` means drop all images on which were based containers.
- `local` Remove only images that don't have a custom tag set by the `image` field (it is non internet loaded images for usual cases).

Comment: Oh yeah, if you make changes to the code, you need a fresh new image as well as container.  One day, someone will come up with an easy way to refresh Docker containers and images easily without having to change the image when the code changes to make dev changes easier.